# How to know how to narrow down the query

Tags: sql

I'm basically learning the SQL on my own and i have a doubt which is mentioned below.

I want to find out the particular employee's salary*12+100 from the employees table.

I have tried in many ways, which is not giving me any result.

Below example is for whole table, however i want to know for particular employee:

```
SELECT First_name, 
salary, 
12*Salary+100
FROM employees;
```

Comment: There is something called `WHERE` clause .. to filter your Query. Say `WHERE First_name = 'your input';`

Answer (score 2):

You really need to give us more information on your table how it is setup to give you a proper answer.

To answer your general question you are going to need to use the `WHERE` clause. What this does in SQL is filters out the data in the table based on the criteria you use in the `WHERE` clause.

For example lets pretend you have a Employe_Id Column that contains the Employee ID. You would do the following.

```
SELECT First_name, 
salary, 
12*Salary+100
FROM employees
WHERE Employe_Id = '123456';
```

What this would do is tell the database is pull the rows that have a value of 123456 in the column Employe_Id.

For more information on exactly what you can do I suggest you take a look at [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp). Which explains it in an easy to understand fashion.